# Need assistance understanding custom uitableviewcell initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

While implementing custom `UITableViewCell` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` whats the difference between these two ways

```
loadNibNamed:owner:options:
```

and

```
SimpleTableCell *cell = [[SimpleTableCell alloc]init];
```

does `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` also `alloc init`? if not how `SimpleTableCell` will work without `alloc init`?

```
SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
```

there is no explicit call of `SimpleTableCell *cell = [[SimpleTableCell alloc]init];`

Comment: Just writing an answer of this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, first off. I'm not actually going to answer the question at all. Instead I'll tell you how to create and use a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. What you're doing at the moment isn't right.

Let's stick to the name `SimpleTableCell` that you have used.

**Create the sub class**

Create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

SimpleTableCell.h

```
@interface SimpleTableCell : UITableViewCell

// if coding only
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *simpleLabel

// if from nib
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *simpleLabel;

@end
```

SimpleTableCell.m

```
#import "SimpleTableCell.h"

@implementation SimpleTableCell

// if coding only
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        //create the simpleLabel and add to self.contentView
    }
    return self;
}

// if from nib no need to do anything at all

// other stuff...

- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    // empty the cell here.
    // means you don't have to empty everything out in the controller
    self.simpleLabel.text = @"";
}

@end
```

OK, so now we have a cell class.

**Create the NIB if that's what you want**

It looks like you're doing this already.

Create the nib with the same name (or not, doesn't really matter).

Make the top level item a `UITableViewCell` and set the subclass to `SimpleTableCell`. Now connect the outlets. In this example `simpleLabel` is all there is to connect.

**Register the subclass with the table view**

In the view controller that owns the table view. This means the table view can deal with creating and dequeueing the cells and you don't have to manually create them at all.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // set up the other stuff...

    // if coding only
    [self.tableView registerClass:[SimpleTableCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SimpleCell"];

    // if from a nib
    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SimpleTableCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SimpleCell"];
}
```

Now you just let the table deal with creating the cells. It keeps track of the reuse identifiers and cell queues so it can handle everything as normal. You just need to ask it to dequeue a cell for you with the identifier you registered you subclass for.

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellFroRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // This API was introduced in iOS6 and will ALWAYS return a valid cell.
    // However, you need to register the class or nib with the table first.
    // This is what we did in viewDidLoad.
    // If you use a storyboard or nib to create a tableview and cell then this works too.
    SimpleTableCell *mySimpleCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    mySimpleCell.simpleLabel.text = @"Hello, World";

    return mySimpleCell;
}
```

**EDIT**

You can create a cell (indeed any class) using...

```
SimpleTableCell *cell = [[SimpleTableCell alloc] init];
```

But doing it this way means it isn't associated to a table view or part of a queue.

One step down (if you like) from the method in my answer is to use the old `dequeuReusableCell...` method and then to check if it's nil and create it like this...

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellFroRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Old way, don't do this if you're targeting iOS6.0+
    SimpleTableCell *mySimpleCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleCell"];

    if (!mySimpleCell) {
        // have to use initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: for the tableView to be able to dequeue
        mySimpleCell = [[SimpleTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleCustom reuseIdentifier:@"SimpleCell"];
    }

    mySimpleCell.simpleLabel.text = @"Hello, World";

    return mySimpleCell;
}
```

I'm not even sure you can load from a nib in here as you wouldn't be able to set the reuse identifier on the cell.

**Multiple cell subclasses**

OK, last edit :D

For multiple `UITableViewCell` subclasses you can use this too. I have done exactly this in the past. You might, for instance, have a cell for a `Post` item a cell for an `Image` item a cell for a `Comment` item etc... and they are all different.

So...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // the rest

    // register each subclass with a different identifier
    [self.tableView registerClass:[PostCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"PostCell"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[ImageCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ImageCell"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[CommentCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CommentCell"];
}
```

To help keep this small (and it comes in handy for NSFetchedResultsControllers too, I move the configuration of the cell out to another method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (the required cell is a post cell) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PostCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self configurePostCell:(PostCell *)cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else if (the required cell is a image cell) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ImageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self configureImageCell:(ImageCell *)cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else if (the required cell is a comment cell) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CommentCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self configureCommentCell:(CommentCell *)cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)configurePostCell:(PostCell *)postCell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // get the object to be displayed...

    postCell.postLabel = @"This is the post text";
    postCell.dateLabel = @"5 minutes ago";
}

- (void)configureImageCell:(ImageCell *)imageCell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // get the object to be displayed...

    imageCell.theImageView.image = //the image
    imageCell.dateLabel = @"5 minutes ago";
}

- (void)configureCommentCell:(CommentCell *)commentCell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // you get the picture...
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for detailed reply, please can you tell me why not use a regular alloc init way for SimpleTableCell? and this is the point where I am all confused.

Comment: thanks so very much for such a great and detailed reply, there is one more thing I want to ask how to handle multiple custom cells using the new api? like 5 different cells in same tableview.

Answer (score 0):

`loadNibNmed:...` is asking the system to recreate an object (usually, but not limited to a UIView) from a canned instance in a nib file.  The nib file is created using the interface builder portion of Xcode.

When an object is loaded from a nib file (`loadNibNamed...`) `init` doesn't get called, instead `initWithCoder:` gets called.  If you're looking to do post initialization setup on a view loaded from a nib file, the usual method is to `awakeFromNib` and call `[super awakeFromNib]`